# How to change error description for custom MSBuild ToolTasks?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task

I have created a custom ToolTask for MsBuild using C#.  This task is used to execute a `nodeJs` script as part of a Visual Studio project build.  This task correctly returns any error output from the tool into the Visual Studio error list, but it is not clear that the error originated from the custom task.

I am concerned that future users, when encountering a build error, may not have a clue that the error is actually occurring inside the custom task.

Is there a way to set any property or meta information (or even customize the output) so that the task reports its name as part of the error description?

See the example below:
[image]

Comment: Maybe you should just add some custom text while logging errorMessage:
`$"[CustomMessage] {errorMessage}"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have authored the custom task (C#?), it should be easy to add extra text to the error message.

Comment: It's a `ToolTask`, so I basically provide path and arguments to the command-line tool, and it's executed and its output and exit code is captured without any intervention on my part.

Comment: @JosephGabriel I do not have visibility into your code, but would the HasLoggedErrors property combined with LogMessage method help?